# R-data visualisation (grouped data)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have two datasets (data frames) with me:

1. Precipitation data (Monthly)
2. SOI index (monthly)

Rather than plotting a scatter plot, I want a grouped plot.

Firstly, I want to group the SOI index into groups such as:

1. very low (magnitude of index less than -1.5)
2. low (magnitude -1.5 to -0.5)
3. moderate (-0.5 to 0.5)
4. high (0.5 to 1.5)
5. very high (greater than 1.5)

Secondly, I want to plot a graph between them such that all precipitation values which match under a common group of SOI index values are plotted above them.

Sample Precipitation Data (24 entries):

```
Jan 1981 61.0
Feb 1981 69.9
Mar 1981 22.9
Apr 1981 291.1
May 1981 153.7
Jun 1981 225.3
Jul 1981 243.9
Aug 1981 132.1
Sep 1981 90.9
Oct 1981 150.9
Nov 1981 127.3
Dec 1981 143.3
Jan 1982 130.8
Feb 1982 110.2
Mar 1982 63.3
Apr 1982 76.5
May 1982 76.2
Jun 1982 45.5
Jul 1982 79.5
Aug 1982 127.0
Sep 1982 140.7
Oct 1982 112.3
Nov 1982 152.4
Dec 1982 270.5
```

Sample SOI Index:
The data is available at "https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/gcos_wgsp/Timeseries/Data/soi.long.data"

Please use the data from JAN 1981 to DEC 1982.

I'm also providing that data below (24 entries):

```
0.27
-0.47
-2.01
-0.60
0.82
1.28
0.87
0.40
0.52
-0.71
0.07
0.41
0.87
-0.03
0.05
-0.46
-0.74
-2.49
-1.89
-2.66
-2.12
-2.20
-3.25
-2.48
```

A reference plot like below is required:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note, SO is Not a code writing service! Show us what have you tried and what does not work.

Comment: @Ashish I tried to go for a direct scatter plot between these two data. But that plot was not very useful from information depiction point of view. So I'm asking whether we can go for this type of plot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is somewhat lacking in effort from your side, hence the down-votes (not mine). There are plenty of tutorials available that should get you started to at least attempt to reproduce the plot you're after.

That aside, the following should give you some ideas; I leave the details up to you. The key is to use `cut` to bin `SOE` values into different groups.

```
setNames(cbind(df1, df2), c("Date", "Precip", "SOE")) %>%
    mutate(SOE.Index = cut(
        SOE,
        breaks = c(-Inf, -1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5, Inf),
        labels = c("very low", "low", "moderate", "high", "very high"))) %>%
    complete(SOE.Index) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = SOE.Index, y = Precip)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```
df1 <- read.table(text =
    "
'Jan 1981' 61.0
'Feb 1981' 69.9
'Mar 1981' 22.9
'Apr 1981' 291.1
'May 1981' 153.7
'Jun 1981' 225.3
'Jul 1981' 243.9
'Aug 1981' 132.1
'Sep 1981' 90.9
'Oct 1981' 150.9
'Nov 1981' 127.3
'Dec 1981' 143.3
'Jan 1982' 130.8
'Feb 1982' 110.2
'Mar 1982' 63.3
'Apr 1982' 76.5
'May 1982' 76.2
'Jun 1982' 45.5
'Jul 1982' 79.5
'Aug 1982' 127.0
'Sep 1982' 140.7
'Oct 1982' 112.3
'Nov 1982' 152.4
'Dec 1982' 270.5", header = F)

df2 <- read.table(text =
    "0.27
-0.47
-2.01
-0.60
0.82
1.28
0.87
0.40
0.52
-0.71
0.07
0.41
0.87
-0.03
0.05
-0.46
-0.74
-2.49
-1.89
-2.66
-2.12
-2.20
-3.25
-2.48", header = F)
```

Comment: Thanks! @Maurits Evers and, sorry for the inconvenience, since as I'm new to R programming so I'm learning a lot of things from experience.

Comment: You're welcome @KaranChaudhary; if this answers your question, please consider closing the question by setting the green check mark next to the answer.